# capistrano でaws にrailsアプリをデプロイすると白い画面が出てエラーになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

capistrano でaws にrailsアプリをデプロイしようとしています。

bash_profileにもsecret_key_baseを設定してもエラーになります。
ログには以下エラーlog/unicorn.log

```
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943197 #23416] ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943289 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943316 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943341 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943360 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943395 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943414 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943431 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943456 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943475 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943495 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in `worker_loop'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943514 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943531 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943548 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943575 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
E, [2016-10-19T21:13:14.943593 #23416] ERROR -- : /var/www/zen/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

confit/secret.ymlは以下の設定をしています。

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: `config/secrets.yml` に `secret_token` と `secret_key_base` がない、というエラーなのですが、それは書いているのでしょうか？そして、capistrano でデプロイしたときに、aws に、`config/secrets.yml` もデプロイ(またはアップロード)されているのでしょうか？

Comment: secret.ymlには上記追記したようにENVを記述してます。またアップロードされています。

Comment: 追記分には `secret_token`がありませんが…。 もしかしたらENVが読み込めてないかもしれませんので直接文字列で `secret_key_base`を書いてみてください。

Comment: 直接文字列で secret_key_base書くと動くんです(^^;;ENVが読み込めないみたいです、bashrcに書いてるのですが‥

Comment: bashrc でどのように書いたのかと、どういうコマンドで起動したのか、を教えて頂けますか